# iPhone : How to fetch data from web service where web service uses "POST" method for JSON?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json, ios4

I want to fetch data from web service using `JSON` in my app.

Web service is developed in C# and it uses `POST` method to pass data.

I found [one example](https://github.com/dcgrigsby/luckynumbers) but its useful only for `GET` method?

So How can I `fetch` JSON data where web service uses `POST` method?

And I also want to `send` data to web service. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sending `POST` request in following way (sending xml with some parameters).

```
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<parameters></parameters>"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.site.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[message length]];

    [request addValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:msgLength                         forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [message release];

    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

To collect data you should implement method:

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

where you should save received data.

In method:

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
```

you can parse that data with some `JSON`-parser.

Hope, that will help you. If you'll have questions about this code ask them in comments.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. But as its my first app with json, Can you please give me some more detail of this above methods? And what is datatype for self.connection ?

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection connection;`. You can read more about that methods in iSO Docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: OK thats good. And do i have to make any object of `JSON` or just need to import "JSON.h" ?

Comment: I've never parsed `JSON` but that question if often asked on SO, just use search =) If you will have problems with parsing you can them in separate question. Now just try to receive data =)

Comment: Hey can you please give me any example or demo ? It will great help to me

Comment: Why don't you want to search? I explain you approach and you now should just try. Search for a `SimpleURLConnections` in iOS Samples